# Task.Run different second execute

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm C# newbie.

Question:

```
class Program
{
    static void why()
    {
        List<Task> listOfDummyTask = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            Task hoho = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Die");
            });
            listOfDummyTask.Add(hoho);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(listOfDummyTask.ToArray());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        why();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        why();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }
}
```

First, I call why(), It prints "Die" same 4 times.

And It prints 1 ~ 4 "Die".

First why() stopwatch returns 28,000 ms, but when I call second why(),

It prints "Die" 8 time, And It prints 5~8 "Die" same time..

Second why() stopwatch returns 10,000 ~ 14,000 ms.

Why?

What Keyword it's situation?

Comment: What do you expect to see when the program runs?

Comment: I think "why()" finished in 2,000 ~ 3,000 ms. But it not. 
And why 2nd executed "why()" increase performance?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task.Run in a loop 100 times will enqueue 100 work items to the default scheduler (thread pool).  If the thread pool decides to execute up to 4 items concurrently, then it will take 4 work items off the queue and complete them in roughly 2 seconds.  Then it will take four more, and so on until all are done.

There's no real expectation of how many tasks will execute concurrently, and how many will be postponed.

Comment: Oh, I See! Can I control dequeue all task at same time?

Comment: You could make a custom scheduler and use it with an overload of Task.Factory.StartNew().  It's still not clear why you'd want that behavior

Comment: I'm making network program use Task.Run to process client's request. First 100 client requests are very slow performance, but next 100 request are fast. So I was wonder this situation. Thank you GregC!!

Comment: I would recommend using ThreadPool for compute-bound algorithms.  Consider using async/await API for performing I/O-bound operations on behalf of your users.  It's hard to say which one you're dealing with, based solely on your question and comments.